# Run cron job every 30 mins even while reboot and startup

Tags: linux, cron

Here is the script for every 30 min

```
00,30 * * * * [path_to_file]/myscript.sh
```

Whats is the script to run the same with each reboot

```
@reboot 00,30 * * * * [path_to_file]/myscript.sh
```

Is the above line right?

Answer (score 2):

no.
These are two separate rules.

```
man 5 crontab
       Instead  of  the  first  five  fields, one of eight special strings may
       appear:

              string         meaning
              ------         -------
              @reboot        Run once, at startup.
```

Comment: so how do I go about doing that?

Comment: with two separate lines

Comment: ok It's still blurry for me. adding both lines in the cron config file , that is all in it ryt?

Comment: or it goes like this, one script file with 30 mins interval code and launch that file every reboot.